# Pre/post load update in the JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have project in Spring Data JPA and Hibernate.

There are two JPA entities - Users and Jobs. Each User has multiple Jobs. Each Job has field Status. When a new Job is created, a new request is sent to a remote server and Job is saved with the status IN PROGRESS.

The updated Status can be queried from the remote server by using it's ID. The requested business logic should be to always return the stored Status, but when the Job is in the IN PROGRESS state, the remote server should be queried for updated status, which should be stored afterwards.

Pseudo code which should explain my intentions:

```
@Entity
class User {
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private Collection<Jobs> jobs;
}

@Entity
class Job {
    private long id;
    private User user;
    private Status status;
    @Inject
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @PrePersist
    private setDefaultStatus() {
        status = IN_PROGESS;
    }

    @PostLoad
    private checkUpdatedStatus() {
        if (this.status == IN_PROGESS) {
            this.status = askRemoteServerForJobStatus(this.id);
            jobRepository.save(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Pseudocode usage:

```
userRepsitory.find(1).jobs // should trigger checkUpdatedStatus
jobsRepository.findAll() // should trigger checkUpdatedStatus
```

I don't think it is a good practice to include jobRepository dependency in the Job entity (as shown in the pseudo code), so my current implementation does all this in the repository - I have methods like findAll() which will call the PostLoad/checkUpdatedStatus-like method. But i have also call this from all other repositories, such as User repository, which also fetches the Job items.

It seems to me like a pretty reasonable use-case so I don't believe, there is no better way to do that. Has anyone already done something like that? I would be really happy if you could get me on the right track.

Thank you,
vlastikcz

Comment: Doesn't see like the correct approach. If the remote server cannot call back with status updates I would consider writing a scheduled task which periodically polls the remote server to query the status of any jobs currently marked as 'in progress' and updates accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, @Alan's comment made me think again and I came up with different approach.

When the Job is created, I start an asynchronous task which simply polls the remote server till it receives an result.

Like this:

```
@HandleAfterCreate
public void addNewRemoteJob(Job job) {
    remoteJobDispatcher.sendRequest(job);
    remoteJobDispatcher.waitForTheResult(job);
}

class RemoteJobDispatcher {
    @Async
    public void waitForTheResult(Job job) {
        while(true) {
            status = askRemoteServerForJobStatus(job)
            if (status != IN_PROGRESS) {
                job.setStatus(status);
                jobRepository.save(job);
                return;
            }
            sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

There might be similar scheduled or perhaps startup job, to work on possible unexpected application states, but it is OK.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Injecting repositories into Entities is not a good move. Entities are persisting structures and the repositories should manage entities not the other way around. Think of transaction demarcations and transient/detached instances.

There's a better way to call a certain login upon adding an entity. You can use an e[vent listener for this](http://reusablecoder.blogspot.ro/2010/09/configuring-spring-managed-hibernate.html). You an configure a load listener that's also a Spring bean, so you can inject other services/repositories in this listener.